# How can I select a line containing "a number before a 'NULL'" in a text file?

Tags: python, regex, file, text

If a line in a text file looks like this, for instance:

```
7     abcdefgh /vol/abcdefgh    /vol/abcdefgh **1384573 NULL**  0   5651572 Share   2   0   CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 0, Remark:   0   NFS /vol/abcdefgh   ntap    None
```

I would like to grab that line, since there is a number before a 'NULL'. How may I go about doing this? Is there a certain search in a text file I can do? I've tried a regular "control f" but that didn't yield what I want.

I've never used Regex but I've heard of it so I'm hoping that isn't my only option. If so, please advise - I use Python. Thank you!

Comment: You haven't showed what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex:

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = """7 abcdefgh /vol/abcdefgh /vol/abcdefgh 1384573 NULL 0 5651572 Share 2 0 CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 0, Remark: 0 NFS /vol/abcdefgh ntap None"""
m = re.search("\d+\s+NULL", s)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

**Output:**

```
1384573 NULL
```

*Edit as per Comment*

```
import re 
with open('inventory.txt', 'r') as s: 
    for i in s.readlines():
        m = re.search("\d+\s+NULL", i) 
        if m: 
            print(m.group())
```

or

```
import re
with open('inventory.txt', 'r') as data:
    s = data.read()
    print(re.findall("\d+\s+NULL", s))
```

Comment: I am trying: import re
with open('inventory.txt', 'r') as s:
    m = re.search("\d+\s+NULL", s)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
but I am getting TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: ('inventory.txt' is the text file where all the lines are stored)

Comment: Try the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you:

```
import re

line_in = "abcdefgh /vol/abcdefgh    /vol/abcdefgh **1384573 NULL**  0   5651572 Share   2   0   CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 0, Remark:   0   NFS /vol/abcdefgh   ntap    None"

output = re.findall (r"(\d+)\s+NULL", line_in )

print (output)
```

The () grabs what is in the parentheses.

The "\d+" finds multiple numeric characters.

The "\s+" finds whitespace.

And "NULL" places it all before the text NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the whole line you could use a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert that the line contains one or more digits `\d+` followed by a whitespace and `NULL`.

[`^(?=.*\d+ NULL).+$`](https://regex101.com/r/F8wWTY/1)

Another way to match the whole line could be to match from the start of the line `^` any character zero or more times `.*`, then match `NULL` and match any character zero or more times to the end of the line `$`.

[`^.*\d+ NULL.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/F8wWTY/2)

If you want to match more than a single whitespace before `NULL` you could repeat the whitespace one or more times `+` or use `\s+` or `\s*` if there could also be no whitespace characters..

Note that `\s`  matches any whitespace character `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`

[Demo Python](http://rextester.com/XHKH24666)